# How to install Firefox Developer edition via Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

This is how to install Firefox via Homebrew:

```
brew install --cask firefox
```

But how to install the 'Firefox Developer edition'?

Everything I tried fails with 'Error: Cask '...' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.'

```
brew install --cask firefox-developer-edition
brew install --cask firefox-nightly
```

What's the correct command?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I've finally found a solution.

Lots of commands on the internet were outdated.

These 2 commands worked for me in 2022 (still working in 2024)

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew install --cask firefox-developer-edition
```

Answer (score 3):

## Homebrew Structure Files

If we go to homebrew repo in our Mac: `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew` we see some folder like `homebrew-core, homebrew-cask, homebrew-cask-fonts` these files are what we get when we run :

```
brew search [formula or cask name]
```

When we do `brew tap homebrew/cask-versions` the [casks files](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions/tree/master/Casks) are cloned to our Homebrew repo. Since that, you may install an alternate cask that was not found before.

For more information, you may found it [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions).